# Is there LAG window function or equivalent in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm trying to query the diff between row values, in SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT timestamp, price - LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as price_diff
from trades
```

But QuestDB returns `Window function expected` error at the position of LAG.

Is there a similar window function in QuestDB that can work instead of LAG?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first_value` window function like to simulate LAG function:

```
first_value(value) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ROWS 1 PRECEDING) as prev_value

... same as

LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
```